# How to crop extra canvas spaces?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, camanjs

My first concern was to fit image <= height of canvas and to that I have used following code..

```
       var canvas = ctx.canvas ;
       var hRatio = canvas.width  / img.width    ;
       var vRatio =  canvas.height / img.height  ;
       var ratio  = Math.min ( hRatio, vRatio );
       var centerShift_x = ( canvas.width - img.width*ratio ) / 2;
       var centerShift_y = ( canvas.height - img.height*ratio ) / 2;  
       ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, img.width, img.height,
                          centerShift_x,centerShift_y,img.width*ratio, img.height*ratio);
```

The above code is working as I wanted ,but when I download the image, the image also contains spaces in both side if the width < height and spaces in bottom at top if the width > height.

Example

Actual Image

```
   _________
  |  (-.-)  |
  |   \|/   |
  |    |    |
  |   / \   |
  |_________|
```

On saving, the image looks something like this

```
   _______________
  |     (-.-)     |
  |      \|/      |
  |       |       |
  |      / \      |
  |_______________|
```

So on saving I don't to save image along with canvas spaces.. Please Help..

Comment: It's all about what do you consider "spaces" an image of a person could contain white color space or the sky as background is that consider "spaces" any way you look at it you will have to loop over every pixels per column and determine if all are space. if they are you can remove that column... but your sample code does not show you attempted anything yet

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know about that..